# How can I remove duplicate data from joining data after group by?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 3 tables likes below erd

[image]

I'm trying to get max number of count product id by desc order count. Then I also add isFavorite depend on user favourites product in  favourites table. **My expected Json looks like**

```
{
    "id": 2,
    "title": "30 % discount on pizza.",
    "price": 100,
    "count": 4,
    "isFavorite": false
},
```

I have tried below query

```
SELECT PRODUCTS.ID AS "Products__id",
    PRODUCTS.TITLE AS "Products__title",
    PRODUCTS.PRICE AS "Products__price",
    (COUNT(INVOICES.PRODUCT_ID)) AS "count",
    CASE
                    WHEN FAVORITES.USER_ID IS NULL THEN FALSE
                    ELSE TRUE
    END AS "isFavorite"
FROM PRODUCTS PRODUCTS
LEFT JOIN FAVORITES FAVORITES ON FAVORITES.PRODUCT_ID = PRODUCTS.ID
INNER JOIN INVOICES INVOICES ON PRODUCTS.ID = INVOICES.PRODUCT_ID
GROUP BY PRODUCTS.ID,
    FAVORITES.USER_ID
ORDER BY COUNT DESC
LIMIT 100
```

Problem is I'm getting duplicate values

[image]

How I will remove this duplicate ?

Comment: Your ERD is missleading. Doesn't show the all relationships arrows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That will happen if more than one user marks the product as a favorite.

The quick answer is to use an aggregate function on the case statement and remove `favorites.user_id` from the grouping:

```
SELECT PRODUCTS.ID AS "Products__id",
       PRODUCTS.TITLE AS "Products__title",
       PRODUCTS.PRICE AS "Products__price",
       COUNT(INVOICES.PRODUCT_ID) AS "count",
       BOOL_OR(    
         CASE
           WHEN FAVORITES.USER_ID IS NULL THEN FALSE
           ELSE TRUE
         END
       ) AS "isFavorite"
  FROM PRODUCTS PRODUCTS
       LEFT JOIN FAVORITES FAVORITES 
         ON FAVORITES.PRODUCT_ID = PRODUCTS.ID
       JOIN INVOICES INVOICES 
         ON INVOICES.PRODUCT_ID = PRODUCTS.ID
 GROUP BY PRODUCTS.ID
 ORDER BY COUNT DESC
LIMIT 100
```

Edit to add:

Your original query had

```
GROUP BY PRODUCTS.ID,
         FAVORITES.USER_ID
```

If a product had more than one user mark it as a favorite, then you would have a row for each distinct `FAVORITES.USER_ID`.

If you simply removed `FAVORITES.USER_ID` from the `GROUP BY`, then you would get an error about how `USER_ID` has to appear in the `GROUP_BY`.

I inferred from your query that you want that to be `true` if any user marked that product as a favorite, so we apply the `BOOL_OR()` aggregate function that returns `true` if any `true` values exist across those rows.

Comment: Genius  ! But I haven't understand how it have solved by aggregate function !

Comment: @AbuSayed I added an explanation for why/how the changes work.